# Why is my GLSL shader rendering a cleavage?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm working on a deferred lighting technique in 2D, using a frame buffer to accumulate light sources using the GL_MAX blend equation.

Here's what I get when rendering one light source (the geometry is a quad without a texture, I'm only using a fragment shader for colouring) to my buffer:

[image]

Which is exactly what I want - attenuation from the light source. However, when two light sources are near each other, when they overlap, they seem to produce a lower RGB value where they meet, like so:

[image]

**Why is there a darker line between the two?** I was expecting that with `GL_MAX` blend equation they would smoothly blend into each other, using the maximal value of the fragments in each location.

Here's the setup for the FBO (using LibGDX):

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.14f, 0.14f, 0.19f, 1); 
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendEquation(GLMAX_BLEND_EQUATION);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_COLOR, GL20.GL_DST_COLOR);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

I don't think the call to glBlendFunc is actually necessary when using this equation. `GLMAX_BLEND_EQUATION` is set to `0x8008`.

```
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec2 v_positionRelativeToLight;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec3 u_lightPosition;
uniform vec3 u_lightColor;

void main() {
    float distanceToLight = length(v_positionRelativeToLight);
    float falloffVarA = 0.1;
    float falloffVarB = 1.0;
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (1.0 + (falloffVarA*distanceToLight) + (falloffVarB*distanceToLight*distanceToLight));
    float minDistanceOrAttenuation = min(attenuation, 1.0-distanceToLight);
    float combined = minDistanceOrAttenuation * attenuation;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(combined, combined, combined, 1.0);
}
```

There are extra variables passed in there as this fragment shader is usually more complicated, but I've cut it down to just show how the attenuation and blending is behaving.

This happens between every light source that I render where they meet - rather than the colour that I'm expecting, the meeting of two light sources - the equidistant point between the two quads, is a darker colour that I'm expecting. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the result of subtracting the first image from the second:

[image: Result of image 1 subtracted from image 2]

The background on the first isn't quite black, hence the yellowing on the right, but otherwise you can clearly see the black region on the left where original values were preserved, the darker arc where values from both lights were evaluated but the right was greater, then all the area on the right that the original light didn't touch.

I therefore think you're getting max-pick blending. But what you want is additive blending:

```
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE);
```

... and leave the blend equation on the default of `GL_FUNC_ADD`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case the blending is *not* additive as I've overridden the default blend equation from additive to the GL_MAX blend equation as described on https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml

My understanding is this will take the component-wise maximum of the RGB values at each pixel using the source and destination colors, so in this case `glBlendFunc` actually has no effect. I tried your suggestion but it gives the same results unfortunately.

Comment: I nevertheless really think you want additive blending, not pick-a-max. Give me a few minutes to edit so that I can upload an image.

Comment: ... or essentially rewrite it. Either way. I think you're currently getting exactly what you ask for, but what you probably really want is additive blending.

Comment: Here is what I get with additive blending, 4 point lights and a blend func of one/one http://imgur.com/Yqimwr4

I want to keep the light amount on a gradient between 0 to 1 without large areas having a value of 1 - I don't want nearby lights to add to each other to create a brighter light overall. 

I appreciate the input though and it's worth at least a vote up from me!

Answer (score 3):

Your result is the expected appearance for maximum blending (which is just like the lighten blend mode in Photoshop). The dark seam looks out of place perhaps because of the non-linear falloff of each light, but it's mathematically correct. If you introduce a light with a bright non-white color to it, it will look much more objectionable.

You can get around this if you render your lights to a frame buffer with inverted colors and multiplicative blending, and then render the frame buffer with inverted colors. Then the math works out to not have the seams, but it won't look unusually bright like what additive blending produces.

Use a pure white clear color on your frame buffer and then render the lights with the standard GL_ADD blend equation and the blend function GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR. Then render your FBO texture to the screen, inverting the colors again.

**Two lights drawn using your method**
[image]

**Two lights drawn additively**
[image]

**Two lights, drawn sequentially with GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO and GL_ADD**
[image]

**The above result, inverted**
[image]

Comment: That's exactly the kind of solution I was looking for, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I just realized you could simplify this. Leave the shader alone and use blend function GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO. Also note that I think the additive version is technically the "correct" way to do a light map, but it might not be the look you're going for.

Comment: Another way you could try doing it is to alpha blend your lights. i.e. in your shader, use `gl_FragColor = vec4(u_lightColor, combined);` and then draw the lights using the standard add blend equation and blend function GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA. I think this is effectively the same as my solution above, but your FrameBuffer will not have to be uninverted.

Comment: This inverse-multiplicative demonstration looks pretty good. I might just have to steal it. I have max-blending lights in my game and I don't like how the cutover point looks.